# More cells then declared gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview..

```
<asp:GridView ID="dvExterneHulp" runat="server" auto AutoGenerateRows="False" GridLines="None"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="mGrid niceTable"
    OnRowDataBound="dvExterneHulp_DataBound" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="odd"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HulpverlenerNaam" HeaderText="Naam hulpverlener" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HulpverlenerAdres" HeaderText="Adres hulpverlener" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uitleg">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Uitleg").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />") %>'
                    Style="word-break: normal; word-wrap: normal;"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DatumBegin" HeaderText="Begindatum" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="klas_id" HeaderText="Klas" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DatumEind" HeaderText="Einddatum" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I want 6 Datafields.. That works, I get the information by a query. But the query has more fields in the results (ids, ...). The extra fields are added at the end, how can I block that?

I can't also access the cells in the RowDataBound to do some custom modifications..

```
protected void dvExterneHulp_DataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dvExterneHulp.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
          e.Row.Cells[4].Text = //GET Datafield klas_id
        service.getKlasNaamById(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[4].Text));
}}
```

I get an error that it is out of range..

Who can help me? I'm trying to understand my mistakes.

Comment: If you use `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`(**EDIT** as you did not as Nima has pointed out) the fields are **not** added automatically to the end. So where are you adding them? According to your second question why you cant acess the cells in the grid from `RowDataBound`: because you haven't checked the `RowState`. You only want `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){}` not the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` too,you set `AutoGenerateRows="False"` now